# Sourcetree can't clone from Openshift

Tags: git, ssh, openshift, sourcetree

I'm trying to clone from `Openshift` with `Sourcetree`. I copied the SSH from `Openshift` into the "Source Path / URL" and then the error:

```
Your SSH agent (Pageant) is running but the server still rejected your connection.  

You may need to load the correct key by double-clicking on the Pageant 
icon in your system tray and selecting 'Add Key'.
```

I've then went to **Tools -> Launch SSH Agent** and nothing happened.

Then I tried **Tools -> Create or Import SSH keys** there I created a new key and uploaded it to `Openshift`, but nothing changed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Open Source tree **Tools > OPtions** and change to openSSH

[image]

Comment: Now you need to create ssh keys and add it to your server. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31552549/github-private-team-separate-ssh-keys/31552753#31552753 read thi sout on how to do it

Answer (score 1):

Use your Comand Prompt to run "rhc setup"

**When installing Ruby, be sure to use Version 1.9.3, instead of the most recent (for Windows).**

You can find instructions here: https://developers.openshift.com/getting-started/windows.html#client-tools