# Cloning with git keeps getting interrupted

Tags: git, ubuntu

I'm setting up the sugar labs development environment on my Ubuntu 15.10 machine. For that, I need to clone their GitHub repositories. I use the command:

```
git clone git://github.com/sugarlabs/sugar-build.git
```

Each time I do this I get the exception:

```
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
```

`github.com[0: 192.30.252.131]: errno=Connection timed out`

However, I know that this is not a problem of internet connectivity as my network speed is upwards of 100 mbps.

What is causing this problem and how do I solve it?

Comment: Can you connect via ssh to github as explained here? https://help.github.com/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection/ . Your firewall might be blocking connections to port 22. Otherwise, try to clone that repo using the https repo url: https://github.com/sugarlabs/sugar-build.git

Comment: try cloning via https: `git clone https://githib.com/sugarlabs/sugar-build.git`

Answer (score 0):

You are likely behind a proxy. Please edit .gitconfig in your user directory according to this:

```
[http]
    proxy = http://your.proxy.net:8080
[https]
    proxy = http://your.proxy.net:8080
```

If your connection still does not work, please check your firewall rules and see if the connection is blocked.

Comment: Yes, I was behind a proxy (of my university). I disconnected my machine from my university's network and set up a hotspot from my phone. I managed to clone the repository from there.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably behind a firewall.

Change the url to `http/http` and it will work for you (a higher chance of not being blocked).

If you switch to ssh remember to create ssh keys under your github account.

Read here how to do it: [Github Private Team Separate SSH Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31552549/github-private-team-separate-ssh-keys/31552753#31552753)